# strange maven behavior with dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project, called `Data_Types`. This is a dependency in a different project called `ApiUse` as such
Data_Types pom.xml

```
  <artifactId>Data_Types</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.10.1</version>
  <name>DataTypes</name>
```

ApiUse pom.xml

```
....
<artifactId>ApiUse</artifactId>
<version>0.0.12.1</version>
   ...
  <dependency>
        <groupId>xxx</groupId>
        <artifactId>Data_Types</artifactId>
        <version>[0,)</version>
     </dependency>
```

when I use the eclipse "Dependency Hierarchy" I get it just fine to the latest version
[image]
The problem arises when I import that second project to a third one.
For some reason even thought I am getting the proper latest version of ApiUse, the it is loading an older version of Data_Types instead of the latest one.
[image]

If I change the declaration from [0,) to 0.1.10.1 It loads it just fine. It makes no sense to me. Any ideas? Thanks
**EDIT**
as you can see from the screen shot, on this particular case the old version is not used, because the same dependency is imported from a different class, and maven is using that other version (which happens to be the latest one, but this is not always the case). In any case this old version should not be imported in the first place. My problem is not that this version is omitted. It shouldn't be there in the first place. I have noticed that even though the latest version is loaded, some methods are loaded from the old version. It sounds stupid, I know, but thats what I have noticed

Comment: There is probably some dependency mediation going on: The version of `Data_Types` is also declared at a different point and that point wins.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd screenshot says the the dependency `Data_Types:0.0.1` was *omitted for conflict*. This means that it is also provided from another dependency.

You can use `mvn dependency:tree` or your IDE features to find out where it comes from.

Supposing you don't have control over all the dependencies, you can use a `<dependencyManagement>` section in your 3rd project to "force" a specific version of `Data_Types`.

---

Also note that it's often not recommended to use non-fixed versions like `[0,)` although it's opinion-based.